# mat-spinner is not showing while loading angular app-root in index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

**Requirement:**

I want to show a `<mat-spinner>` while loading the `<app-root>` in `Angular`

**Code tried:**

*index.html:*

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading ...
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

*app.module.ts:*

```
import {
   ...,
   MatProgressSpinnerModule,
   ... }from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

**Version info:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

**Result:**

Its showing `Loading ...` but not showing `<mat-spinner>` , tried spinner alone as well as with "Loading ..." text as given above, but the result is same - `<mat-spinner>` doesn't show.

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/

Comment: inside component selector if you write any other selector, that will be removed/replaced by angular by the template of that component, that's why spinner is not visible. you should use content projection for this.

Comment: @ashishpal , thank you.. let me check ..

Comment: I used a custom css and some divs to achieve this, but not by using any external components/modules. Can this help you?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i tried this way some, but didn't work for me .. can you please get me some sample codes or any ref link ?

Comment: sure, I'll post an answer

Comment: @ashishpal, Content Projection will help to push some data into the component right ? but here i don't to send anything to component , instead i need to display a spinner or loader while loading the component, once loaded it should disappear .. just like "Loading .." test works if we give .. am i wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a custom css and class to achieve that. All this code is inside the `index.html`

```
<style>
    @-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.center-page{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.pulse {
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 1.0
}


@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {opacity: 1.0;}
  49% {opacity: 1.0;}
  50% {opacity: 0.0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.0;}
}
</style>

<body>
    <my-app>
        <div class="center-page">
            <img class="spinner rotating" src="yourImageToRotate.png">
        </div>
    </my-app>
</body>
```

The result is this image rotating endlessly

[image]

I've also used, in some project, a pure css spinner and it works like this:

```css
<style>
 .center-page{
        display: flex;
        width:calc(100vw - 40px);
        height:calc(100vh - 40px);
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
 
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
        width: 33%;
        height: 33%;
        background-color: #333;
        float: left;
        -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
        animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
              animation-delay: 0.3s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
              animation-delay: 0.4s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
              animation-delay: 0.1s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
              animation-delay: 0.3s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
              animation-delay: 0s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
              animation-delay: 0.1s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }
 
    @-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
    0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
                transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    } 35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
                transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    }
    }
 
    @keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
    0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
                transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    } 35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
                transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
    }
    }
 </style>
```

```html
<div class="center-page">
        <div class="sk-cube-grid">
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its working for me .. thank you .. i did kind the same before, but didn't work out, i might have missed something . not sure why .. anyway .. thank you for sharing the code with me..

Comment: If you have to the code I can help you out understing why it wasn't working. Anyway, no problem!

Answer (score 4):

While application initially loads angular hasn't loaded the `App module` yet so it doesn't know what `mat-spinner` is at that point.

You would need to use something that's is not angular if you want to show any thing before the modules are loaded. Your best shot would be a `gif-spinner`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the exact issue. I will try with some custom CSS now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already answered; using an angular component does not work before your app has loaded. Instead of using a completely different spinner than angular material, you can take the approach of copying the markup and styles to reproduce it in the `<app-root>` of your `index.html`.

Here is a link to a gist that uses this approach:
https://gist.github.com/DanRibbens/00dc9e971b0df9f58c3726885a2a59aa#file-index-html

Answer (score 0):

Use `<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>` in app.component.html (template which has selector name app-root).

You can use `ngIf` condition to show spinner in template untill all the required things are ready to be shown. PFB the sample

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isReady">
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<mat-spinner *ngIf="!isReady"></mat-spinner>
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isReady = true;
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: why the timeout function ? loading may or may not take 5 seconds right ? if use in this way we can use ngInit to set isReady right ? but still by this solution, if we need to see the spinner, the component constructor should load - but if can give inside the selector, it will show even from before anything loading from component .. right ?

Comment: It's just a sample. you can replace anything in component class which will satisfy your business condition. Example: Triggering a API call or running some functions.